# Unable to add table on database in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel-6

First I run the following command.

```
php artisan make:model member -m
```

After that it creates a member, then I run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

It migrates successfully, but the member table did not get created in the database.

**Migration**

```php
class CreateMembersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('fullname');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('members');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your migration

Comment: @aynber I added this

Comment: @tithidey This migration works fine. Is your database info correct in your .env file?